# Access Denied by User while pip upgrade Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I am new to python. I am trying to install some package in Python 2.7. When I am trying pip install (package_name) it asking to upgrade pip version. In my system it is 9.0 now it 18.0 is available. When I am trying to upgrade pip it processes to uninstall and install the new version. But I am the user of my system and access is denied by the administrator to remove the old pip.

I am also tried easy install (package-name)

It causing me a problem to install the package. Is there any way to install the package without upgrade pip either programmatically or command line. Let me know

Comment: Possible duplicate of [upgrade pip without root access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35806451/upgrade-pip-without-root-access)

Comment: You really should not be learning Python 2 in 2018. The supported and recommended version of the language is Python 3. By the original timeline, Python 2 should be dead already (though it was given a couple of additional years in terminal care after all).

Comment: I would suggest you to look into using `virtualenv` and then installing packages through pip inside virtual environment.

Comment: @tripleee there are still many software APIs that use 2.7 eg Abaqus

Comment: There are some reasons to *also* learn Python 2 but in the absence of evidence to the contrary, those are missing.